# PHP switch not switching with integer

Tags: php, switch-statement

I have an HTML form and some PHP, but it always echo's "100 TEST" regardless of the case submitted. The default case works fine.

HTML:

```
<form class="page-search" action="page.php" method="post">
     <input type="text" name="page" autofocus maxlength="3" placeholder="100" style="width: 50px;">
     <input type="submit" style="visibility: hidden;">
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php 
$pageid = isset($_POST['page']);

switch ($pageid) {

case '100':
echo '100 TEST';
break;

case '200':
echo '200 TEST';
break;

case '300':
echo '300 TEST';
break;

default: 
echo 'DEFAULT';
break;

}
?>
```

Have I missed something really obvious? I'm kicking myself for needing to ask the question but can't seem to figure this one out!

Comment: [**RTM**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) You are assigning the return value of `isset()`!

Comment: Looking at the `switch` usage in the example you might be better of not using it at all. If this is really all it need to do you can achieve it with a one liner `echo isset($_POST['page']) ? $_POST['page']  . ' TEST' : 'DEFAULT';` ill add this to my answer just incase :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
$pageid = isset($_POST['page']);
```

To

```
$pageid = isset($_POST['page']) ? $_POST['page'] : 'default value if you need one';
```

Since the code is checking the result of the `isset()` method which will be a `boolean`, but the `switch` is interested in the `$_POST['page']` value itself.

---

As mentioned in my comment here is an alternative for the example code:

```
echo isset($_POST['page']) ? $_POST['page'] . ' TEST' : 'DEFAULT';
```

Comment: *Change* Why?, **why** change it?

Comment: Because the code is not checking the  `$_POST['page']` value in your code. And instead you are checking the result of the `isset()` which will be a `boolean`

Comment: ^ Then add this explanation to your answer, so everyone will know what's going on with the code and why they have to change it like this.

Comment: I knew it would be something dead simple. Thank you for your help, this has solved my issue!

Answer (score 0):

`isset` Returns TRUE if var exists and has value other than NULL, FALSE otherwise.

change your code to this

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['page'])) $pageid = $_POST['pageid'];
```

Answer (score 0):

isset will return the boolean value. So here it makes the issue.

You are not closed ur close bracis for switch also, isset is checked but value is not assigned for variable $pageid

```
$pageid = isset($_POST['page']) ? $_POST['page'] : 0;

switch ($pageid) {

 case '100':
 echo '100 TEST';
 break;

 case '200':
 echo '200 TEST';
 break;

 case '300':
 echo '300 TEST';
 break;

 default: 
 echo 'DEFAULT';
 break;
}
```